# Jest methods not available in .spec.js files

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I started a simple project with npm init, then added jest via

```
npm install jest
```

How do I make methods like `describe()`, `test()`, etc., available in .spec.js and .test.js files?

Comment: If you're using raw javascript it should work out of the box. Are there any other ways you've configured your project besides the commands `npm init` and `npm install jest`? If not, you should be able to run your tests using `npx jest` or setting your "test" script to "jest" and using `npm run test`

Comment: What happens when you write `describe()` in the spec file now?

Answer (score 0):

The `jest` methods will be available when you run `jest`.

Probably your ESLint configuration is not configured for jest and shows that these globals are missing, you can configure them in the [eslint configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring):

```json
"env": {
    "jest/globals": true
}
```